# Woocommerce and discontinued products

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Currently running a webstore off the back of woocommerce. Recently we've had several products that have become discontinued and assumed there would already be a built in process to handle discontinued products that tells the customer that the product has been discontinued also not lead to a dead page taking seo considerations into account.

To our surprise we couldn't find any native option without compromising seo efforts that handles discontinued products. After days and days of researching we have come to the conclusion that no one really knows and suggest a variety of conflicting views.

Our products run through this life cycle:

1. In stock - Active product and in stock to purchase
2. Out of Stock - Active product but currently out of stock, pending restock
3. Discontinued - Inactive product, end of life product, no longer being sold and no longer being restocked.

The part I am struggling with is how to handle point 3 as woocommerce seems to mix both 2 & 3 with no actual option for discontinued products. Suggestions I have come across

1. Do nothing with discontinued products - Many things wrong with this option, catalog full of unnecessary discontinued products, bad user experience, you can not discern if a product is out of stock or discontinued.
2. Delete discontinued products - Bad for seo, you lose all the link juice of ranking discontinued products unless a custom 404 page is created to redirect users to related products and imagine 404 pages lose ranking over time.
3. Mark products as out of stock and hide from archive pages - Means legitimate active products that are out of stock are also hidden along with discontinued end of life products
4. Link  [here](https://www.stryde.com/seo-considerations-for-discontinued-products/) suggested there is a plugin to handle discontinued products but appears no such thing exists.

So my question is how do people truly handle discontinued products on their woocommerce sites to mark products discontinued, without tanking seo rankings for those pages whilst making "active out of stock" products still visible and completely seperate to discontinued.

Answer (score 1):

First, you cannot delete the discontinued product as past orders have a reference to discontinued products - customer may want to view a product he/she previously ordered.

WooCommerce has a filter 'woocommerce_product_is_visible' that you can use to control catalog visibility on individual products. You should use this to hide discontinued items from the catalog. I would change the product title to have a prefix 'Discontinued - ' and filter on that.

**Even easier, you can just set the "Catalog visibility" field to "hidden" in the Publish box of the editor.**